# New to Rstudio and R, trying to figure out this problem for a stats class

Tags: r

New to R and Rstudio, using these programs for a stats class. I've never used these programs so I don't know how different they are to some of the intro programming classes I've taken. My professor gave us a list of basic commands to graph stuff in Rstudio, but nothing beyond making some graphs and mean, median, mode, etc. There is a homework problem that is asking about C02 emissions in different countries. The data set is just two columns, country on the left, and C02 emissions on the right. I'm trying to find all of the numbers in the data set that are above the mean which is 4.97.

I tried running this in the console, I got all of the numbers that were > 4.97 but in a list form. There is a long list of like 200 numbers or so after running that in the console. I was wondering if there is something I can add to the code to just return the number of items that are returned (numbers greater than 4.97). It's been a while since I've taken a programming class and I'm not sure how r or rstudio is compared to like java or python. Usually I think I would type something like count+, ++i, or return(i)? It's been so long I don't remember, any help of this would be appreciated. Again sorry if this is a dumb quesiton, I'm new to r, rstudio, and stack overflow, and I can't find an accurate thread for what I need for this problem.

[Rstudio Screenshot, code in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGEEO.png)

Comment: Your class needs to provide better lessons on how to use R ... `subset(chapter2problems, \`CO2 emissions\` > 4.97)` is all rows that meet that condition, and `nrow(subset(...))` tells you how many rows there are in that frame.

Comment: While you _can_ do `for`-loops in R, it is generally much better to use the vector as a whole. For instance, pseudocode might suggest `for (i in 1:10) if (vec[i] > 5) vec[i] else vec[i] + 100`, in R one would instead do `ifelse(vec > 5, vec, vec+100)`. There is a lot that can (and should) be done in R using vectorization, and generally R is more efficient doing it that way than the more brute-force `for`-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is a vectorized language which makes it significantly different from a more procedural language like python.

Using your example:

```
meanCO2 <- mean(chapter2problem2$`CO2 emissions`)
```

Will return the mean value.  Now the vectorized approach:

```
chapter2problem2$`CO2 emissions` > meanCO2
```

Will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE on whether the value is > mean.
So

```
sum(chapter2problem2$`CO2 emissions` > meanCO2)
```

Will sum up the True values (TRUE=1 and FALSE=0).
Or to select the values one could use to select the rows greater than the mean:

```
chapter2problem2$`CO2 emissions`[chapter2problem2$`CO2 emissions` > meanCO2, ]
```

See this page for an introduction: https://www.datacamp.com/cheat-sheet/getting-started-r
Here is a good cheatsheet which I still use: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Just tried it and got exactly what I was looking for! Your explanation was great, and thanks for the resources!